# Can comparison operator overloading in Kotlin be used to implement SQL like functionality?

Tags: operator-overloading, kotlin

Kotlin has limited operator overloading. I'm wrapping an API that does vector-based operations, as they are done in languages like R, Julia, APL, etc. The most common example is in SQL where you can say:

```
select * from foo where bar > 3;
```

such that each record is evaluated individually, and added to a result-set if it passes the comparison. In Kotlin, comparison operator overloading is associated with a compareTo method:

```
Expression  Translated to
a > b   a.compareTo(b) > 0
a < b   a.compareTo(b) < 0
a >= b  a.compareTo(b) >= 0
a <= b  a.compareTo(b) <= 0

All comparisons are translated into calls to compareTo, 
that is required to return Int.
```

So it appears to me there is no way to use operator overloading to express a vector-oriented comparison operation. Am I missing something?

A work-around would be to create functions using the infix keyword like:

```
infix fun greaterThan(x: Int)...
```

which could be invoked as:

```
where(bar greaterThan 3)
```

but this isn't nearly as legible

Comment: It seems like you already know the answer.  Or are you asking "can I change the compiler behavior to not convert comparisons to `compareTo()`?  which is a must simpler question (no, you cannot).  Have you looked at the SQL libraries for Kotlin that exist to see what they already do (Exposed, Squash, JOOQ)?

Comment: @JaysonMinard I knew what the documentation said, but hoped there was a way to hack around the limitation to get the syntax I wanted. That doesn't seem to be the case.  I have (since posting) looked at Exposed, which uses  the same .eq(someValue) you would use in Java, which is ok, but I'm trying Kotlin because I was hoping to improve on Java.

Comment: There is talk about AST support in Kotlin down the road, which would allow some manipulation of what is going on, when that happens it might help you along these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin do have these features, but not in the form you have thought. Kotlin is a *general* programming language that is a mix of OOP and FP, not a domain specific language. Kotlin tend to solves thing by functions, not operators/language constructs. For example, kotlin use `filter` function to achieve what SQL `where` clauses do.

<sub>However some of these functions are actually mimmicing builtin language constructs.</sub>

```
fooCollection.filter {it.bar > 0}
```

In the above code `fooCollection` is a `Collection<Foo>` (and `Foo` is a POJO/java bean mapped from the record of your table `foo`).

If you are not clear with anything I posted above, please let me know by commenting below.

Comment: This looks reasonable. I think I will accept this answer after experimenting as I don't believe it's possible to do exactly what I would like.  However, I continue to feel that this construction is less elegant than the table[column > 3] syntax you get in some other languages